# Stripe undefined

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I've got a problem with Stripe, I added to 'package.json' this line: `"cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "7.0.*"` and then used `composer update`. I hope I did it right. But I get undefined on Stripe type.

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Stripe\Checkout\Session;
    
    use Stripe;
    
    class StripeController extends Controller
    {
        public function stripePost(Request $request)
        {
    
            Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));  // Stripe\Stripe is undefined
            Stripe\Charge::create ([  // Here is fine
                    "amount" => 100 * 100,
                    "currency" => "usd",
                    "source" => $request->stripeToken,
                    "description" => "This payment is tested purpose"
            ]);
       
            Session::flash('success', 'Payment successful!');  // Here flash is undefined method
               
            return back();
            
        }
    }
```

I added comments where it's working and where I'm getting undefined. I also tried `composer require stripe/stripe-php`, but that didn't help. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do not edit `composer.json` directly. Use `composer require cartalyst/stripe-laravel` from the command line. Version 7.0 is 5 years old and likely unsupported. Let composer decide what version is best to install.

Comment: Hello, okey I used this, it installed `"cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "^13.1",` but in that code Stripe is still undefined, have syntax changed if that was such an old version? @miken32

Comment: I have no idea, I would guess there is documentation telling you how to use it and what the appropriate class names are.